# How can I repair the BIOS on a chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I was installing the BIOS on my Chromebook to replace ChromeOS with Windows and I lost internet connection before the process was complete I turned off the Chromebook now it won't turn on how can I fix this?

Comment: What does it do ?  What do you see ?

Comment: I try to turn it on by the power button and the screen stays black, it does not show anything

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I was installing BIOS on my Chromebook to replace ChromeOS with Windows and lost internet connection before the process was complete. I turned off the Chromebook and now it won't turn on. When I try to turn it on the screen does not show anything it stays black.

Comment: I think that since the BIOS installation process to install Windows did not finish, that is why the chromebook does not turn on and in the process the ChromeOS Bios were lost, I would like to know if there is a way to install a bios in these conditions that allows the Chromebook to boot .

Answer (score 1):

1. [Try pressing](https://www.howtogeek.com/190645/how-to-factory-reset-a-chromebook-even-if-it-wont-boot/) <kbd>Refresh</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd>.
2. For [HP Chromebooks](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Black-screen-couldn-t-power-off-after-BIOS-update/td-p/8317290): "Press and hold the Windows + b keys, and continue to press those keys while you press and hold the power button for 2 to 3 seconds. Release the power button, but continue pressing the Windows + b keys..." Wait about a minute to see BIOS update screen. Check [link](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Black-screen-couldn-t-power-off-after-BIOS-update/td-p/8317290) for more info.
3. [Try disconnecting battery](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/comments/42iqx7/blank_screen_after_bios_update/) for a while.
4. [Reflash BIOS chip externally.](https://scottenock.com/articles/unbrick-your-chromebook) This is not for the technically unskilled or faint of heart, and might be best performed by an *experienced and knowledgeable* service technician!

Comment: I already tried with Refresh and power and nothing happens, the chromebook model is Asus C423NV